# XML Indent and no standalone

Tags: java, xml

I have an unformated XML file (Just one line) and i would like indent it :

My File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><test>toto</test></Document>
```

My java code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class PrettyXmlFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args != null && args.length > 0  && args[0].length() > 0)
        {
            String FileInputName = "TEST.xml";//"args[0];"
            runFormat(FileInputName,true);
        }
    }

        public static void runFormat(String FileInputName, boolean standelone) throws Exception {


                String FileOutputName = FileInputName + "MOD";
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(FileInputName)));
                doc.setXmlStandalone(standelone);
                prettyPrint(doc,FileOutputName);
        }

        public static final void prettyPrint(Document xml , String FileOutputName) throws Exception {
            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            PrintWriter FileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(FileOutputName));
            tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(FileOut));
        }

}
```

I have tried to play with the doc.setXmlStandalone(standelone);

With doc.setXmlStandalone(true) i have this result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test>toto</test>
</Document>
```

With doc.setXmlStandalone(false) i have this result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test>toto</test>
</Document>
```

I would like i result with standalone value and an escape after the xml declaration like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test>toto</test>
</Document>
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC` to yes

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "yes");
```